# Test Graphql API - python

Tags: python, testing, graphql

I'm using graphql (graphene) on a flask application and I want to test that my graphql is working as expected. I looked into apollo but it looks like it only supports node, java and ruby... not python. Does anyone know of any similar tools that I can use to test that the server fires up correctly, renders the graphql interface and returns the correct values when inputting a query?

Comment: Are these programmatic or manual tests?

Comment: Jake, I would like them to be programmatic tests.

Comment: I'm not well verse in python, however what I do in JavaScript is this. I create the executable schema with some in memory models and then for each test I setup a executable schema and then run my tests against that. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL includes a nice out-out-of-the-box GUI called GraphiQL that runs in the browser. It will show comments in your code as documentation, show what fields/variables are available and their type, and autofill the query.

```
from flask_graphql import GraphQLView

app.add_url_rule('/graphql', view_func=GraphQLView.as_view('graphql', schema=schema, graphiql=True))
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-GraphQL

https://github.com/graphql/graphiql